# ASP Classic searching multiple

Tags: asp-classic

Question: anyone have multiple searching coding using asp ? Can you share?

This is what I want to do..

There are 3 option or searching..by name, by location, by region

For the first display all data with paging..on top it has searching.

```
<textfield>name</textfield><list/menu>location</list/menu><list/menu>region</list/menu>
```

when search by region it will display all region are selected.
Then it allow to filter by name to get specific

```
 <%
   Dim adoCon        
   Dim rsGuestbook    
   Dim strSQL          
   Dim lngRecordNo    

   lngRecordNo = CLng(Request.QueryString("ID"))

   Set rsGuestbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

   'Initialise the strSQL variable with an SQL statement to query the database'
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Master WHERE ID=" & lngRecordNo

   rsGuestbook.Open strSQL, oConn
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a querystring search be name,department,age. It works properly. It might help you. Just fetch your values. Put those in proper places. And don't forget to change your tablename

```
    name1=request.QueryString("name")
    dept1=request.QueryString("dept")
    age1=request.QueryString("age")

sqlStr="Select * from Student_Entry"
    sqlWhere=""

    if name1<>"" then
        sqlWhere = " Where S_name='"&name1&"'"  
    end if
    if dept1<>"" then
        if sqlWhere = "" then
            sqlWhere = " Where S_dept='"&dept1&"'"
        else
        sqlWhere = sqlWhere&" And S_dept='"&dept1&"'"
        end if  
    end if

    if age1<>"" then
        if sqlWhere = "" then
            'sqlWhere = " Where  S_age="&age1&""
            sqlWhere = " Where  S_age"&agestr&age1 

        else
            'sqlWhere = sqlWhere&" And  S_age="&age1&""
            sqlWhere =sqlWhere&" And S_age"&agestr&age1
        end if  
    end if

    sqlStr = sqlStr & sqlWhere
```

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are describing multiple dependent lists (?)

there is an example here with demo:

http://www.aspkey.net/aspkey/_articles/asp/showarticle.asp?id=100

Comment: thanks..there we need to select all then output process..it hard to me to modify the code so that output will appear when first selected tick.none to select 3 of them

Answer (score 0):

```
strname , strlocation and strregion value will depend on selection if not select then default value will be "". 

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Master WHERE ID=" & lngRecordNo 

if strname <> "" THEN
strSQL = strSQL & " and name ='"& strname &"' "
END IF 

if strlocation <> "" THEN
strSQL = strSQL & " and location='"& strlocation &"'
END IF 

if strregion <> "" THEN
strSQL = strSQL & " and region='"& strregion &"'
END IF

rsGuestbook.Open strSQL, oConn
```